# Get all distinct values in a column as an array from a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In Rails, how can I get all distinct values from a column, as an array?

```
Matches
-------
winner_id     loser_id
1             2
1             3
1             4
1             5
```

I want to get all the distinct IDs in `winner_id` column, and all the distinct IDs in `loser_id` column.

Running `Match.select(:winner_id).distinct.to_a` does not work. It returns an array or record objects like this `[#<Match id: nil, winner_id: 1>, #<Match id: nil, winner_id: 2>]`. I'm trying to get a result like `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pluck` to get an array

```
Match.pluck(:winner_id).uniq
```

Comment: Amazing. Now if I want an array of unique IDs between winner_id and loser_id should I just do `Match.pluck(:winner_id, :loser_id).uniq` then merge the resulting array? `[[1],[2,3,4,5]]`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question

Comment: To get an array of unique ids from both, you can do `Match.pluck(:winner_id, :loser_id).flatten.uniq`